# Meteor 1.1 - Error: spawn ENOENT on Windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, meteor, runtime-error

Everything happens with Meteor 1.1.0.2

I've been developing a meteor app for quite some time now and with the 1.1 release of meteor I switched my dev environment from linux VM to Windows 8.1 (my everyday working machine). Everything has been working great so far, no issues being present at all, until today.

**After deploying my app today, everything seems to work fine for 10-15 seconds and then the app crashes and console starts to throw the following error, which is thrown continuously, every second:**

```
W20150504-14:21:21.355(2)? (STDERR) wmic spawn error: Error: spawn ENOENT
```

What's important to note is that I did not touch any core files prior to this thing happening and that the problem occurs only on my machine (my co-worker uses Windows 7 and everything works fine) and it is bound only to this particular project.

Here is a list of packages I use, maybe it will give you a hint as to what it might be:

```
meteor-platform
iron:router
ddp
accounts-password
jquery
meteorhacks:fast-render
meteorhacks:subs-manager
meteorhacks:npm
accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
twbs:bootstrap
upload-jquery
reactive-var
fortawesome:fontawesome
mizzao:jquery-ui
edgee:slingshot
check
tracker
fourseven:scss
npm-container
sacha:spin
meteorhacks:cluster
aldeed:autoform
ovcharik:alertify
mjn:famous
gadicohen:famous-views
meteorhacks:kadira
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this issue by removing Kadira from my project. I still have no idea why did it make my Windows 8.1 throw ENOENTs so if anyone knows, I would really appreciate your input.